# Передача аргументов

Tags: c++, функции

Функция, в зависимости от принимаемого int аргумента выводит сообщение: 0-«раз», 1-«два», 2-«три».
Другие значения кроме этих трёх функция принимать не может. Как реализовать это «ограничение». Язык : C++.

Comment: Кратко: никак. Вы просто можете ничего не выводить, или сгенерировать при передаче такого аргумента исключение, но не допустить передачи какой-нибудь четверки не получится. Да и как бы вы хотели это сделать? Если задуматься — то что должно происходить при передаче неверного аргумента?

Comment: Мне так вот поставили вопрос на интервью. Не «возможно ли так сделать?», а именно «как это реализовать?». 
В моём представлении это только проверка уже пришедшего аргумента в функцию, но как это можно сделать при передачи аргументов - я понятия не имею. Подумал что есть какая-то фишка, о которой я не знаю, вот и задал этот вопрос сюда

Comment: возможно они хотели услышать про enum? хотя это тоже не стопроцентная защита

Comment: Непонятно в чем проблема так сделать. Обычный `switch` и 3 `case`. *"Другие значения кроме этих трёх функция принимать не может."* - эта фраза вроде как никак не подразумевает изобретения каких-то хитроумных мер защиты от передачи других значений. Но вообще могли бы уточнить. у спрашивающего

Comment: Это и есть проверка пришедшего уже в функцию аргумента. Интересует есть ли возможность исключить отправку других значений

Comment: Нет, но этого и не требуется. Хотите исключать отправку других значений - это вам надо в Ada/SPARK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем все эти сложности с экзепшном и косвенностями? Если функция не может принимать никакие другие значения кроме заданного интервала, то в корректно написанной программе эти значения просто не должны ей передаваться. А для того, чтобы отловить передачу ошибочных значений на этапе отладки, специально придуманы ***ассерты***!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <assert.h>

void func(int val)
{
    static const char* nums[] = {"раз", "два", "три"};

    assert ((val>=0) && (val<3));
    printf("%s\n", nums[val]);
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    func(0);
    func(1);
    func(2);
    func(-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Будет выведено (в отладочной сборке):

```
раз
два
три
Assertion failed: (val>=0) && (val<3), file main.cpp, line 9
```

Comment: Это, увы, не защита от передачи неверного параметра, и по сути ничем не отличается от других методов, разве что тем, что если все же будет передано неверное значение, то в релиз-версии оно попадет в функцию...

Comment: @Harry, вы правы только насчёт того, что это один из методов защиты. Однако в этом и весь смысл ассертов, что они не должны попадать в релиз-версию, ровно как и неверные значения не должны передаваться в функцию в полностью отлаженной программе. Ассерты как раз защищают программиста от собственных ошибок, с помощью которых последний выявляет их и исправляет. Ну а если всё же есть страх, что какой-нибудь косяк просочится в релиз, то можно собирать бета-версию, в которой все ассерты оставить. В прочем, вы и так прекрасно знаете всю эту кухню.

Comment: @Harry ну а что конкретно использовать: assert'ы, if'ы, "прокси"-функцию или всё вместе, зависит от конкретного ТЗ и особенностей реализации. Ни один из методов не лучше и не хуже, каждый имеет свою нишу применения. Впрочем, это тоже довольно очевидные вещи))

Comment: Именно. Обратите внимание на последнюю строку моего ответа: *Словом, увы, но при нечетко заданном ТЗ (**а оно задано нечетко!**) результат один — ХЗ...*

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще один вариант...

В программировании очень многое решается введением уровня косвенности. Давайте введем дополнительную функцию, типа

```
void proxy(int x)
{
    if (x >= 0 && x <= 2) func(x);
}
```

И вызывать будем только ее. Тоже ведь вариант — `func` никогда не получит на вход ничего неразрешенного :)

Но меня терзают смутные сомнения, что от вас хотят чего-то такого:

```
enum class VAL { _0 = 0, _1 = 1, _2 = 2 };

void func(VAL x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
    case VAL::_0: cout << "раз"; break;
    case VAL::_1: cout << "два"; break;
    case VAL::_2: cout << "три"; break;
    }
}
```

Другое дело, что это все равно не убережет от неверного вызова a la

```
func(static_cast<VAL>(5));
```

Есть и еще один вариант — класс, обеспечивающий неявное приведение в `int`, но, например, генерирующий исключение при передаче неподходящего значения.

Словом, увы, но при нечетко заданном ТЗ (а оно задано нечетко!) результат один — ХЗ...

Answer (score 1):

Я бы решил это так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_func(unsigned par1)
{
    if (par1 > 2)
    {
        throw runtime_error("unvalid parameter");
    }
    cout << par1 + 1 << endl;
}

int main()
{
    print_func(0);
    print_func(1);
    print_func(2);
    //print_func(3); - exception
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: тип аргумента в вопросе **int**

Comment: @AlexGlebe Нет смысла использовать тут int. По условию число ниже 0 так же неприемлемо. unsigned это те же 4 байта, что и у int.  Только int может хранить от -2^32/2 до 2^32/2, а unsigned  от 0 до 2^32

Answer (score 0):

Если условия не использовать шаблоны нет, то можно сделать просто:

```cpp
void print(int I) { /*...*/ }

template <int I>
void foo() = delete;

template<>
void foo<1>() { print(1); }
```

И написать отдельные реализации для каждого числа от 1 до 3. Если пробрасывать туда другие числа, то просто компилироваться не будет. Но, честно говоря, проверить не могу, так как с телефона. И не уверен, что msvc пропустит.

Comment: Или даже через `sts::enable_if` для одной функции